# Is there a way to extract data from prefetch in order to pass as a parameter to another prefetch in React-query

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-query, static-site-generation

The title says it all, basically.

I fetch some data and then I want some additional data, but I need an ID value which I can only get from the first fetch's data. The whole page is SSG and I was wondering if there is a way to implement this logic with prefetch using react-query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`queryClient.prefetchQuery` doesn't return any data on purpose, however, you can use `queryClient.fetchQuery` instead, which does return data. But keep in mind that you need to handle errors, because `fetchQuery` doesn't do that, while `prefetch` does. In fact, this is the whole implementation of `prefetchQuery` (leaving out the TS generics for brevity):

```
prefetchQuery(options) {
  return this.fetchQuery(options).then(noop).catch(noop)
}
```

Comment: Coming in clutch as always! Thank you